# Laravel 5.2 update table with newly added record with AJAX without reloading page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

My question is a bit specific ... I have a simple form in Laravel and on some of those fields I bind pop up windows with simple table ...

I need to achieve, that when you click on the icon after input field, popup will show up and you can insert via AJAX fields to the table .. This works perfect, until you want too see newly added record in the popup .. when I want to see it, i need to reload the page and open the popup again ...

Here comes my source ...

This my **VIEW**:

```
{{ Form::label('department_id', 'Department:') }}
{{ Form::select('department_id', $departments, $emp->department_id, array('placeholder' => 'Choose department ...')) }}

<a href="" id="firePopup_department">
<img src="{{ URL::asset('img/future.png') }}" alt="add_future_fields" title="Add future fields" class="add_future_icon"/>
</a>              

<div id="department_content" title="Departments" style="display:none">   
 <div class="future_field_form">                                                         
  {{ Form::label('dpt_new', 'Department:', array('class' => 'future_field_label')) }}
  {{ Form::select('dpt_new', $departments, null, array('class' => 'future_field_input dpt_new', 'placeholder' => 'Choose department ...')) }} 
  <br />
  {{ Form::label('dpt_from', 'Valid from:', array('class' => 'future_field_label')) }}
  {{ Form::date('dtp_from', null, array('id' => 'from', 'class' => 'future_field_input dpt_from')) }} 
  {{ Form::submit('Save', array('class' => 'future_field_button', 'placeholder' => 'Submit')) }}  
  <br />  
 </div>
 <p class="future_field_msg"></p>

<table class="future_field_table">
  <tr>
    <th>Value</th>
    <th>From</th>
    <th>To</th>  
    <th class="sys_action">Delete</th>  
  </tr> 
 @foreach($future_fields as $ffield) 
  @if($ffield->field_name == 'department_id')     
    <tr>
      <td>{{ $departments->get($ffield->field_value) }}</td>
      <td>{{ $ffield->valid_from }}</td>
      <td>{{ $ffield->valid_to }}</td> 
      <td class="sys_action"><a href="#" title="Delete">delete</a></td> 
   </tr> 
 @endif
@endforeach
</table>
</div>
```

This is **AJAX** I am calling (fired by event OnClick on *.future_field_button*)

```
$( ".future_field_button" ).click(function() {  
    var field_value = $('.dpt_new').val();  
    var valid_from = $('.dpt_from').val();
    var field_name = 'department_id';  
    var emp_id = $('.emp_id').val(); 

    //alert(field_name + " => " + field_value + ", " + valid_from + " for: " + emp_id);


    // get real data
    $.ajax({  
      headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      },
      method: "POST",
      url: '/add_future_field',
      data: { field_value: field_value, 
              valid_from: valid_from, 
              field_name: field_name,  
              emp_id: emp_id, 
             },
      // results on ERROR or SUCCESS 
      error: function(xhr, status, error){
           $('.future_field_msg').css('color','red').text("Error! Contact admin ...");
      },
      success: function(data){
          if(data == 'both_missing'){
            $('.future_field_msg').css('color','red').text("Both fields must be filled!");
          }else{
            $('.future_field_msg').css('color','green').text(" " + data);
          }
      } 
    })
});
```

**Route** is pretty simple:

```
Route::post('add_future_field', 'EmployeeController@add_future_field');
```

and finally **Controller**:

```
public function add_future_field(Request $request){ 

         $field_value = $request->input('field_value'); 
         $valid_from = $request->input('valid_from'); 
         $field_name = $request->input('field_name'); 
         $emp_id = $request->input('emp_id');
         $changed_by = Auth::user()->id; 

         if($field_value == '' || $valid_from == '') {
           return "both_missing";
         }else{ 

           // insert data
           $ffield = new FutureField;
           $ffield->employee_id = $emp_id; 
           $ffield->field_name  = $field_name;
           $ffield->field_value = $field_value;
           $ffield->valid_from  = $valid_from;
           $ffield->valid_to    = '3000-01-01';
           $ffield->created_by  = $changed_by;
           $ffield->save();


           // get new actual results  
           $future_fields = array (
                'future_fields' => FutureField::select('id', 'employee_id', 'field_name', 'valid_from', 'valid_from')
                                            ->where('field_name','=', $field_name)         // only selected one   
                                            ->get(),
                );     
           return $future_fields;  
           //return $field_name.";".$field_value.";".$valid_from.";".$emp_id.";".$changed_by;                           
          }   
    }
```

I am not able to parse final $future_fields (with newly added records) to the destination table (view) .. can you help me how to do it? What am I missing?

Everything works well, until getting the up2date data ... they are inserted but now shown in the pop up window :( In the *future_field_msg* (p tag) i recieve `[object Object]` 
message in green color

Thank you

EDIT:
I've found one possible solution how to potentially deal with it .. after successful ajax request, I hide the table in div and rebuild it with jquery in the same structure again ... but is there is more sophisticated way how to achieve it? this sounds me like a 'nasty' workaround :) I'd prefer clean solution

### SOLUTION (thx to @Thomas Van der Veen )

Controller:

```
return response()->json($future_fields);
```

Ajax: (only the success part)

```
 success: function(data){
              if(data == 'both_missing'){
            $('.future_field_msg').css('color','red').text("Both fields must be filled!");
          }else{                    

            // get table body and remove it
            $('#department_content .future_field_table > tbody').empty(); 

            // transform JSON object to JS array
            var future_fields = data.future_fields;

            for (i in future_fields) {

               var future_field = future_fields[i];

               // generate new row content
               var newRowContent = "<tr><td>"+future_field.field_value_display+"</td><td>"+future_field.valid_from+"</td><td>"+future_field.valid_to+"</td><td class=\"sys_action\"><a href=\"#\" title=\"Delete\">x</a></td></tr>";

               $(newRowContent).appendTo($('#department_content .future_field_table > tbody'));                    
            }                                      

            $('.future_field_msg').css('color','green').text(field_value_display+" inserted!");
          }
      }
```

But I'm now facing the issue, that I am not able to repopulate the table with default {{ }} echo function in laravel .. I need to generate this

```
<td class="sys_action">
  <a href="#" title="Delete">
    <img src="{{ URL::asset('img/delete.gif') }}" class="future_field_edit_img" alt="delete" />
  </a>
</td>
```

How could I do it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller you will have to return json.

Like this:

```
return response()->json($future_fields);
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#json-responses)

In your javascript you will have to loop this data and add them to the table.

Example:

```
success: function(data)
{

    for (i in data)
    {

        var future_field = data[i];

        // Populate table

    }

}
```

**Edit after OP update**

Instead of rebuilding the entire table you can remove the old rows and add new.

Example:

```
$table_body = $table.find('tbody');

// Remove all table rows
....

$table_row = $('<tr><td class="somecolumn"></td><td class="othercolumn"></td></tr>');

for (i in future_fields)
{

    var future_field = future_fields[i];

    // Fill table row with desired values
    //
    $table_row.find('.someclumn').html(future_field.somevalue);

    $table_row.find('.otherclumn').html(future_field.othervalue);

    // Append new table row to tbody
    //
    $table_body.append($table_row);

}
```

This code has not been tested but should be working (I think)

Comment: cool thanks, that's what I've just realized :) so is this the cleanest solution??

Comment: There are always enough ways to get cleaner code :) I always "try" to write code that is readable for others (even if no one is ever going to read it). You could change the data variable to future_fields since it only contains objects of future_fields.

Comment: thx... I made it work ... check up the final solution in my last edit ... but what I am facing now is, I am not able to use laravel native echo {{ }} in the jquery ... but I need to add there delete and link information ...

Comment: Well it is obvious you can't execute php with javascript inside a browser. Is creating an url what you want to do? Maybe [this](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/) is interesting for solving that problem.

Comment: actually it isn't ...  my concern was to do it dynamically (but you're right ... it's not possible to do it inside js) .. i just did it as fixed url (absolute) but i am now facing another problem... my table is repopulating correctly but the last td cell in table should server for AJAX deletion ... on the first page refresh, it works ok .. but when I repopulate the table the onClick event ain't triggered by ajax :( but the table looks pretty same (when I compare the source code)

Comment: finally !!! I've found the solution ... i was using `$( ".drop_dpt_futureField" ).click(function(e){ ` instead of `$( document.body ).on( "click", ".drop_dpt_futureField", function(e) {` ... problem was with my dynamic content which needs to be "parsed" by the second call !!